# Are these two spaces of functions identical?

Tags: real-analysis, geometric-measure-theory

Let the function space $A$ denote all functions $f : [0, 1) \to [0, 1)$ such that, for some set $Z$ of Lebesgue measure zero, the derivative $f'$ exists on $[0, 1) \setminus Z$ and $|f'| = 1$ there.

Let the function space $B$ denote all functions $f : [0, 1) \to [0, 1)$ such that for all $a < b$ in $[0, 1)$, the portion $G_f(a,b) = \{(x,f(x)) ∈ \mathbb R^2 \mid a \le x < b\}$ of the graph of $f$ that lies above $[a, b)$ has Hausdorff $1$-measure $H_1(G_f(a,b))$ equal to $\sqrt 2(b - a)$.

(Note that we do not assume functions to be continuous.)

Does $A = B$?

It is [**not**] clear that $A$ is a subset of $B$ — **in fact this is false** — so the real question is whether the reverse inclusion holds.

Thanks to Christian Remling, it appears that the *only* question is whether B is a subset of A.

(This was posted to MathStackExchange for over a week without any answers or mathematical comments.)

Comment: It is not true that $A\subseteq B$: Consider $f(x)=x-g(x)$, where $g$ is a rescaled version of the Cantor function, increasing from $0$ to $1/2$ on $[0.5, 0.50001]$ and otherwise constant. Then the graph of $f$ on this interval connects $(0.5,0.5)$ to $(0.50001,0.00001)$.